# How can I use promises to handle a MySQL connection NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

I'm developing something for a school project using NodeJS and a MySQL server, and I am trying to create a wrapper function that handles the connection and then uses a callback to any other functions I need to use, but I'm having problems getting the first two functions in the handler to execute and then waiting for the callback to entirely execute before closing the connection. How can I do this?

The error I am getting is "Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state".

```
let mysql = require('mysql2');
let con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '',
    user: '',
    password: ''
})

function connectionHandler(_callback) {
    con.connect(function (err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log('Connected!');
    });

    con.query('USE test', function (err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
    });

    _callback;

    con.end(function (err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
    });
}

function addOrder() {
    con.query('INSERT INTO orders', function (err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
    });
}

connectionHandler(addOrder());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use callbacks, try to change your logic like this:

```
let mysql = require('mysql2');

let con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '',
  user: '',
  password: '',
  database: 'test'
});

function connectionHandler(_callback, dbName = 'test') {
    con.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;

        con.query('USE ?', [dbName], function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        
            _callback();
        
            con.end(function (err) {
              if (err) throw err;
            });
          });
    })
}

function addOrder() {
  con.query('INSERT INTO orders', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
}

connectionHandler(addOrder(), 'test');
```

Comment: Even nesting the functions like that, I still get the error that the there is no selected database, so somehow the callback is still being called before the 'USE test' query.

Comment: @Mr.Goose Try to specify a default database in `createConnection`, then pass a parameter to `connectionHandler` containing the target database for the query (see edited answer).